# Automatic SMS Verification in Chrome Custom Tabs

Tags: android, one-time-password, chrome-custom-tabs

We have a native Android app, but our Login and Signup are done in Chrome Custom Tabs via mobile number and One Time Password.

Is there a way to read the One Time Password from the SMS and prefill it on the webpage for the user as we do in Native Apps.

Comment: You can read SMS in Android and then try to pass a code to web-page. Do you really need CCT, not WebView?

Answer (score 0):

The [Web OTP API](https://web.dev/web-otp/) seems to be what you are looking for. It's not launched yet, but you can try it in [Chrome Beta](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chrome.beta).